# Grey Scroll Pane Background Image in JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, javafx, background-image, scrollpane

I'm using JavaFX in Eclipse from JDK 1.8.0_72. I want to display an image in the background of a scroll pane. I'm using the following code to do this:

```
ScrollPane s2 = new ScrollPane();
s2.setContent(label);
s2.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('DungeonRoomImage.png');");
```

This works just fine on other objects such as Labels and GridPanes but for some reason not on scroll panes where it's displaying a grey block in the middle covering up the image. If you look closely between the border and grey center you can see the image peeking out.

https://gyazo.com/597ce351f158c1d66c33fe301bd75feb

The same issue occurs when changing the background color of a scroll pane, but is solved by using

```
-fx-background:
```

instead of:

```
-fx-background-color:
```

I've tried using setBackground but that renders the same result

```
s2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image("DungeonRoomImage.png"), null, null, null, null)));
```

Could anyone suggest a way to get rid of the grey background or a way to work around the issue?
Here's how the background image should look

https://gyazo.com/f84873278507700aea17452321b80b20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background image on the scroll pane's viewport. Using an external CSS file:

```css
.scroll-pane .viewport {
    -fx-background-image: url('DungeonRoomImage.png');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using setStyle?

Comment: Not easily. Using external style sheets is highly recommended anyway.